# Is smite damage affected by Barbarian Rage/Frenzy?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, barbarian, damage-resistance, rage

I've got a question regarding the mechanics of the game.

In theory the Barbarian Rage reduces the damage Barbarian takes by a half (piercing/bludgeoning/slashing).

The weapon type used to cause the damage doesn't matter (so both normal and magical weapons damage is reduced).

Now the question is what is the actual nature of smite damage. Is it imbuing the weapon strike with additional damage type or an effect which occurs during the strike (like lighting bolt strike on hit).

The TL/DR is - Paladin strikes Barbarian with a weapon attack and uses Divine Smite. The weapon damage is halved. What about smite damage?

Bonus question: What about weapon imbued with multiple kinds of damage like Slashing + 1d4 fire (is fire damage halved as well?).

Comment: Is the smite damage piercing, bludgeoning, or slashing?

Comment: That's actually what I am trying to establish. The true nature of smite damage. Is it like imbuing a weapon with radiance or more like a "radiant bolt" striking the enemy the very same moment weapon strike occurs.

Comment: Don't the smite abilities say what type the damage is?

Comment: It does say radiant. If I do understand your logic correctly than weapon dealing fire damage should also by able to bypass reduction.

Comment: My logic is to just look at the type of damage. If the resistance is to X and the damage is Y, it doesn't get reduced. But your question implied that smite damage is part of what the character is resistant in. I don't know paladin abilities by heart and I don't have access to check them at this moment.

Comment: If you are looking to defeat a barbarian, hit them with a wisdom save if you have one available, but know that oathbreaker is amazing, so this is your opportunity to change subclass and I would seriously consider it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Divine Smite damage is not (generally) reduced by rage

Divine Smite (p. 85, *PHB*) says:

> Starting at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one paladin spell slot to deal **radiant** damage to the target, in addition to the weapon’s damage

The barbarian's Rage only gives damage reduction to bludgeoning, piercing or slashing damage (p. 48 *PHB*), no other types:

> You have resistance to bludgeoning, piercing, and
> slashing damage

Because of this, the rage does not reduce any radiant damage or fire damage. The source of the damage (i.e. if it is part of the weapon's damage or not<sup>1</sup>) does not really matter: the damage reduction is general and would apply in either case.

Only if you are a Path of the Totem Warrior Bear berserker, then the damage would be reduced because that subclass also has resistance to radiant damage when raging (p. 50 *PHB*)

> ***Bear***. While raging, you have resistance to **all damage
> except psychic damage**

---

<sup>1</sup> It isn't. This damage does not count as weapon damage, it is **in addition** to the weapon's damage. It would however coount for critical hits, because those double all damage dice in the attack.

There even is a Sage Advice Compendium entry on this:

> **Does the benefit of the Savage Attacker feat apply to
> additional effects like the rogue’s Sneak Attack or the
> paladin’s Divine Smite?** No. The benefit of Savage Attacker
> applies only to rolls of the weapon’s damage dice,
> not to any extra damage that a feature or other ability
> might grant.

This makes it explicit that Divine Smite damage is not part of the weapon's damage dice.

P.S. Regarding your reason for asking: **Make sure you check with the other player first.** You should try to discuss this with them out of the game before having your character attack their character. At some tables, Player-vs-Player is fine and accepted, at others it is frowned upon or outright banned. You should not just assume that this is OK without checking with them, if you do not want to end up with bad blood amongst players that is a lot worse and problematic than how to calculate damage of the attack.

Comment: Am I correct to assume than that this lack of reduction should also apply to the additional weapon damage of non-phosical type like 1d4 fire etc ? It seems that my DM has been wrong on that one as well.

Comment: Yes, normal rage does only give resistance to the 3 physical damage types, none of the others.

Answer (score 8):

Divine Smite ability clearly says:

> Starting at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one spell slot to deal **radiant** damage to the target, **in addition** to the weapon's damage.

So, you roll it separately from your weapon damage and it's not halved by resistances that don't say that they resist radiant damage (For example barbarian, who picked Totem Warrior subclass and Bear Totem Spirit - has resistances to all damage, except psychic).

Same with any other cases of damage that is dealt **in addition** to weapon's damage.